# Can I use soy butter instead of olive oil for baking vegetables?

Tags: butter, roasting, olive-oil

I'm putting olive oil (probably too much) in my oven tray when roasting vegetables, potatoes, poultry, etc.

**Can I use soy butter instead of olive oil?**

Alternatively, what are some cheaper types of oil that I can use for baking vegetables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Put it on the vegetables not on the tray.**

Anything not on the vegetables is wasted.  You can put a little bit on them then roll them around with your hangs.  Olive oil is good for roasting.  Just skimp on it.

You can bake with any bland oil.  I used to keep corn oil for baking.  It is cheap and flavorless.  Sunflower oil is pretty cheap too, and it has a little bit of flavor that I think goes well with baked goods.  That is what I was using until I used it up this week.

Comment: @dragonmnl please don't ask about health on our site, it is a big no-no topic, even outside of the main question.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at it, Soy Butter is made with soy beans and canola oil or grape seed oil (or other types of vegetable oil).

If not wanting to use olive oil, use good canola oil or other vegetable

I never used Soy Butter, but you should try it, but I expect that the soy part of it might burn.